# Convert String to GET request Parameter in Dart using standard library

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-http

I have a multiword String that I'd like to convert to a GET request parameter.

I have an API endpoint `/search` that takes in the parameter `query`. Now typically your request would look like `http://host/search?query=Hello+World`.

I have a `String` *Hello World* that I'd like to convert to this URL encoded parameter.

Ofcourse, I could just write the logic to break it into words and add a `+` in between but I was wondering if the [URI class could help with this](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html)

I'm using Dart's `httpClient` to make a request.

```
Future<String> _getJsonData(String queryToSearch) async {
  List data = new List();
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();

  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(
      config['API_ENDPOINT'] + '/search?query=' +
          queryToSearch));

  var response = await request.close();
  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
    var jsonString = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    data = json.decode(jsonString);
    print(data[0]);
    return data[0].toString();
  } else {
    return "{}";
  }
}
```

Essentially, need to encode `queryToSearch` as the URL parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Uri.http(s)` which wrap everythings (query, host, and path) together and encode them accordingly.

```
    final uri = new Uri.http(config['API_ENDPOINT'], '/search', {"query": queryToSearch});
```

Comment: Just what I needed. I was trying `Uri.ecode` but that's for encoding the POST body. The documentation wasn't very explicit about passing queries like this in GET requests

Answer (score 3):

The [Uri](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri-class.html) class provides methods for that

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri/encodeQueryComponent.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri/encodeFull.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Uri.parse(url_string)` if you have the full URL in this way.

```
final String accountEndPoint = 'https://api.npoint.io/2e4ef87d9ewqf01e481e';

Future<Account> getAccountData() async {
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse(accountEndPoint); // <===
      final response = await http.get(uri);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> accountJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return Future.value(Account.fromJson(accountJson));
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to get account');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
```